# Extracting currency value in Google Sheets with regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am trying to extract the tip value from columns in Google Sheets.  What would be the proper regex argument to use to do this?  Some columns do not have the tip value, and in this case i would like it to return "0".

```
Tip - 20% x $134.00Damage Waiver: 5% x $40.20Coupon: Thanks for considering us!! x -$10.00Tax: 7.25% of $700.20 x $50.76
```

Comment: So what is the generic format? What should be the output for this example?

Comment: In this example the output should be "$134.00".

Another common entry would be in this format "Damage Waiver: 5% x $16.50Tax: 7.25% x $25.12" with no "Tip" entry.  In this case I want it to return "0".

Comment: But what is the fixed part and what is dynamic in this format? What is the pattern that follows "Tip" in case it is there? Is there always a hyphen, always 20%, always "x", ...? Can you be explicit about the format with all its possible variations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input string (let's say at A1) has the word "Tip", and the first dollar symbol after that initiates the amount of interest, then do:

```
=IFNA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\bTip\b[^$]*\$([\d.]+)")), 0)
```

This expression will produce a *number* type, so the dollar is not included.

Apply the desired number formatting to the cell where you place this formula to show a currency symbol, and the required number of decimals.